# How to make the text form field as interactive in SingleChildRenderObjectWidget?

Tags: flutter, rendering

I used SingleChildRenderObjectWidget to construct a widget in which I have drawn the text form field widget in paint method with the help of paintChild method. But the text form field is not interactive, how to make this text form field interactive.

Code Snippet:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Sample'),
      ),
      body: InteractiveViewer(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
            ),
            const DrawCanvas(
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        

borderSide: BorderSide(width: 3, color: Colors.blue)),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(width: 3, color: Colors.blue)),
                        labelText: 'NAME',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }  

    ///
    class DrawCanvas extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
      const DrawCanvas({
        Widget? child,
      }) : super(child: child);
    
      @override
      RenderCanvas createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
        return RenderCanvas();
      }
    }
    
    class RenderCanvas extends RenderProxyBox {
      RenderCanvas({
        RenderBox? child,
      });
    
      @override
      void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
        if (child != null) {
          context.paintChild(child!, const Offset(550, 200));
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: in most cases you dont need your own renderObjects, but in case you are sure: renderObjects dont automatically update, you have to set them dirty with `markNeedsLayout();`, see https://youtu.be/cq34RWXegM8

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Reason : `hitTest` fail
`context.paintChild(child!, const Offset(550, 200));` 
you paint child in `Offset(550, 200)` cause `hitTest` fail

Solution : if it's typo, you can do `context.paintChild(child!, offset)` 
 or you can pass offset and override `hitTestChildren` see below

code snippet

```
class RenderCanvas extends RenderProxyBox {
  final Offset translation;
...
bool hitTestChildren(BoxHitTestResult result, { required Offset position }) {
        assert(!debugNeedsLayout);
        return result.addWithPaintOffset(
          offset: Offset(translation.dx , translation.dy),
          position: position,
          hitTest: (BoxHitTestResult result, Offset position) {
            return super.hitTestChildren(result, position: position);
          },
        );
      }
...
context.paintChild(child as RenderObject, offset + translation);
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Sample'),
      ),
      body: InteractiveViewer(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
            ),
            const DrawCanvas(
              translation: Offset(550, 200),
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(width: 3, color: Colors.blue)),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(width: 3, color: Colors.blue)),
                    labelText: 'NAME',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DrawCanvas extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  final Offset translation;

  const DrawCanvas({
    required this.translation,
    required Widget child,
  }) : super(child: child);

  @override
  RenderCanvas createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return RenderCanvas(translation);
  }

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(BuildContext context, RenderCanvas renderObject) {
    renderObject.translation = translation;
  }
}

class RenderCanvas extends RenderProxyBox {
  RenderCanvas(
    Offset translation,
  ) : _translation = translation;

  Offset get translation => _translation;
  Offset _translation;
  set translation(Offset value) {
    if (_translation == value) {
      return;
    }
    _translation = value;
    markNeedsPaint();
    markNeedsSemanticsUpdate();
  }

  @override
  bool hitTest(BoxHitTestResult result, {required Offset position}) {
    return hitTestChildren(result, position: position);
  }

  @override
  bool hitTestChildren(BoxHitTestResult result, {required Offset position}) {
    assert(!debugNeedsLayout);
    return result.addWithPaintOffset(
      offset: Offset(translation.dx, translation.dy),
      position: position,
      hitTest: (BoxHitTestResult result, Offset position) {
        return super.hitTestChildren(result, position: position);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    if (child != null) {
      context.paintChild(child as RenderObject, offset + translation);
    }
  }
}
```

execution result

[image]

Comment: @Deepika, does this answer work for you?